# Create a formula for counting working days without weekends and public holidays SharePoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint, excel-formula, formula

I came up with the logic of the calculation, but I don't know how to write it down in a formula, help, for example, the new year, I want to count like this
***- if 01.01.2023 is in the range Start day - End day, then it is equal to 1.***

I use the usual formula to count the number of weekdays and subtract what I count.

Comment: so, [`NETWORKDAYS.INTL`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28) does not works for you?

Comment: No, it's working only with Excel. =(